# Arithmetic operations with Collection Java

Tags: java, collections

I need to create static methods of arithmetic operations(+, -, *, /) with Collection. Type of return value is Collection. Please, give me an example of some operation or explain how to do it. I have two Collections and i need to add, subtract, multiply and divide them. I need to create static method for each operation.

Comment: Your question going to be closed, elaborate more. It's unclear what you are asking

Comment: Ok. I added some information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me quess what you want. Here you have got a class with static method which takes two lists:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Operations {

    public static Collection<Integer> add(List<Integer> l1, List<Integer> l2) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < l1.size(); i++) {
            result.add(l1.get(i) + l2.get(i));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here you have got a Main class where you can see how to use it:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    private static List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private static List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        list1.add(1);
        list1.add(2);
        list1.add(3);

        list2.add(10);
        list2.add(11);
        list2.add(12);
        Collection<Integer> result = Operations.add(list1, list2);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Now, you can implement other methods (copy and paste method **add** and change **+**):

```
minus -
multi *
divide /
```